# Image header for post doesn't display in blogdown post

Tags: r, blogdown

I am using the `blogdown` and the `wowchemy-hugo` theme to create a website in R. I've created a post, however the image that I've inserted in my YAML isn't apprearing in the header for some odd reason. I have saved the image in my folder under `static\image\headers\gdp.jpg`, am I missing something?

```
---
title: "This is my title"
author: "This is my name"
date: 2020-09-10T21:13:14-05:00
tags: ["Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"]
header:
  caption: 'Image Credit: [**AvaTrade**](https://www.avatrade.com/education/trading-for-beginners/gross-domestic-product)'
  image: 'headers/gdp.jpg'
  focal_point: ""
  preview_only: false
output: html_document
---
```

TIA!

Comment: I didn't test it, but the image path might be `/image/headers/gdp.jpg` instead of `headers/gdp.jpg`. More info: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-files.html

Comment: @YihuiXie tried that out now but it didn't work either. Quite strange because I managed to do this a few months back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what the issue is. The image needs to be saved in the `media` subfolder within `static` (instead of under `image`). See: https://wowchemy.com/docs/managing-content/

Comment: Thanks for posting back! It's unfortunate and frustrating that this theme went through so many (backward incompatible) changes...